# TypeError: _firebase2.default.storage is not a function (Jest test failure)

Tags: reactjs, firebase-storage, jestjs

I have a simple shallow test.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Layout from '../containers/'

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  shallow(<Layout />);
});
```

Upon adding `firebase.storage()` functionality to my app (not in Layout.jsx directly but in the child of children of Layout) - i am now failing this simple test. I was under the impression that a shallow render here would be... well, shallow... no?

It should be noted that all of my firebase components work just fine and i'm not getting any errors anywhere other than this failing test.

I have tried bringing in `import 'firebase/storage'` but this doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the implementation of Layout component and the component that uses `firebase.storeage()`? Using `shallow` will indeed only render the Layout component without children, but that doesn't mean that the other component will not be imported, so if you are using that function at the top level, it would explain why it is failing. Another option, try disabling the lifecycle methods with this option: http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#arguments

Comment: Sure. My layout component consists of my router and Route components from react-router-dom. That's all that's going on there. The component that uses firebase.storage is in a ```<Route path='/path' component={ComponentThatUsesStorage}/>``` which is rendered in Layout. I'll look into that link here now.

Comment: I'm not using any lifecycle methods in my layout component. That's a good option to know about though! Like i said, my layout component is literally only rendering Route components and nothing else.

Comment: is the statement with `firebase.storage()` *inside* a component method or outside of the actual component, but in that file? That file is probably imported by the `Layout.jsx` component, so all the code at the top level will be executed. However, the code inside the component should not be executed as `shallow(...)` does not render the components.

Comment: ahhh... good idea. let me check.

Comment: So... firebase.storage() is exported from my ```lib/firebase``` file and only imported one time in my ```fileUploadModal``` which is triggered from one of the routes rendered in Layout... it's weird. it does not exist anywhere outside of this. I'm gonna test and remove that modal to see whats what.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

I overwrote the test script in `package.json` to `react-scripts test --env=jsdom  --browser` and it worked.

Comment: sweet! thanks for the input! ill get back into this project and accept your answer if it works! cheers!